# Javascript Set Object Adding

Tags: javascript, object, reference, set

Why this code output of both are different as adding objects in set make compare references?
Code 1

```
let list = [ {a:1,b:1},{a:2,b:3},{a:3,b:1} ]

let set = new Set(list);

let newList = [{a:1,b:2},{a:3,b:1}];
set.add(...newList)

let newFilteredList = [...set]
console.log(newFilteredList)
```

Code 2

```
let list = [ {a:1,b:1},{a:2,b:3},{a:3,b:1} ] 
let newList = [{a:1,b:2},{a:3,b:1}];
let employees = [...list, ...newList]
let set = new Set(employees)

let newFilteredList = [...set]

console.log(newFilteredList)
```

Code 1:

```
(4) [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}]
0 : (2) {a: 1, b: 1}
1 : (2) {a: 2, b: 3}
2 : (2) {a: 3, b: 1}
3 : (2) {a: 1, b: 2}
[[Prototype]] : []
```

Code 2:

```
(5) [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}]
0 : (2) {a: 1, b: 1}
1 : (2) {a: 2, b: 3}
2 : (2) {a: 3, b: 1}
3 : (2) {a: 1, b: 2}
4 : (2) {a: 3, b: 1}
[[Prototype]] : []
```

Comment: The key difference between the two snippets is when the duplicates are removed. In the first snippet, duplicates are removed before adding the new elements, so only the unique elements from list are present in the final result. In the second snippet, duplicates are removed after adding the new elements, so both the unique elements from list and the new elements from newList are present in the final result.

Comment: @Shibi no, that makes no actual sense. 1. That's not at all how sets work. 2. That's not the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Set#add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/add) does not accept variable number of arguments. `.set(...newList)` just adds the first item because the method has a single parameter.

```js
const set = new Set();

set.add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

console.log(set.size);
```

Comment: thanks for help. I have missed that  spreading will make different params.